# Angular instantiate class error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I try to instantiate a class in Angular 4 I get this error:

`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`

**admin.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from '../event';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
})
export class AdminComponent {
  onSubmit() { 
    const event = new Event('foo', 'bar');
  }
}
```

**event.ts**:

```
export class Event {
    constructor(
        public event: string,
        public comments: string
    ) { }
}
```

Following various StackOverflow answers I tried a different `event.ts` but it produced the same error:

```
export class Event {
    event: string;
    readableDate: string;
    constructor(public event: string, public readableDate: string) {
        this.event = event;
        this.readableDate = readableDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Event` class in the statement

```
const event = new Event('foo', 'bar');
```

and to which one it refers. It may be confused with Angular's or Javascript's `Event` class.